# Accessing Users of a group

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I make the following query

```
$group = Group::with('user.campaign')->where('groupName', 'TeamA')->get();
```

This returns something like the following

```
Collection {#429 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Group {#398 ▼
      #table: "user_groups"
      #guarded: []
      #attributes: array:5 [▶]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "User" => Collection {#402 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            0 => User {#409 ▶}
            1 => User {#410 ▶}
            2 => User {#411 ▶}
            3 => User {#412 ▶}
            4 => User {#413 ▶}
          ]
        }
      ]
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

So I can see User is within the relations.  However, I am having issues accessing the users which are apart of the Group TeamA.
If I try

```
$group->user
```

I get an error.  Unfortunately, my error page at the moment only seems to say something went wrong, without any details.

How would I go about accessing the users of this group?

Thanks

Comment: You have defined the relation as `User` and accessing it as `user`. (the case of the first letter is different). As @Roboticsexpert has mentioned it is better to name it as `users` following the convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have some mistake on that , User field is a collection ...

that mean , User field is not instance of User class and is collection of users

```
"User" => Collection {#402 ▼
          #items: array:5 [▼
            0 => User {#409 ▶}
            1 => User {#410 ▶}
            2 => User {#411 ▶}
            3 => User {#412 ▶}
            4 => User {#413 ▶}
          ]
        }
```

i suggest you to rename User field in Team class to Users.

after that it's good to know, property name should be camel case ...